# How would I add multiple entities from a List to my SQL database?

Tags: c#

I have a List converted from an IEnumerable and I am trying to dump it into my database. For this example, I have 12 records and I am attempting to use a foreach to process all records. The problem is that when the records are added, I get a Primary Key Violation when I have the `SaveChanges()` method inside the loop and when it is out side the loop, I get a Guid of all zeros.

My code is:

```
public UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnits_Create(IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound> _UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound)
{
    UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound = new UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound();
    UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage _oUnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage = new UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage();
    UnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit = new UnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit();
    List<UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound> _listUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound = _UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.ToList();
    foreach (UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound _RelatedUnit in _listUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound)
    {
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.Active = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.Active = _RelatedUnit.Active;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.BaseUnitAbbreviation = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.BaseUnitAbbreviation = _RelatedUnit.BaseUnitAbbreviation;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.BaseUnitID = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.BaseUnitID = _RelatedUnit.BaseUnitID;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.BaseUnitName = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.BaseUnitName = _RelatedUnit.BaseUnitName;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.Name = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.Name = _RelatedUnit.Name;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.RelatedUnitAbbreviation = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.RelatedUnitAbbreviation = _RelatedUnit.RelatedUnitAbbreviation;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.RelatedUnitConversionRatio = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.RelatedUnitConversionRatio = _RelatedUnit.RelatedUnitConversionRatio;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.RelatedUnitDisplayOrder = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.RelatedUnitDisplayOrder = _RelatedUnit.RelatedUnitDisplayOrder;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.RelatedUnitName = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.RelatedUnitName = _RelatedUnit.RelatedUnitName;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.UnitOfMeasureSetID = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.UnitOfMeasureID = _RelatedUnit.UnitOfMeasureSetID;
        _newUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound.UnitOfMeasureTypeID = _oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit.UnitOfMeasureSetID = _RelatedUnit.UnitOfMeasureTypeID;
        _oDBContext.UnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnits.Add(_oUnitOfMeasureSetRelatedUnit);
    }
    _oDBContext.SaveChanges();

    return _oUnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage;
}
```

My SQL schema is:

```
[ID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
[Name] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
[Active] [BIT] NULL,
[UnitOfMeasureID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NULL,
[BaseUnitID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NULL,
[BaseUnitName] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
[BaseUnitAbbreviation] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
[RelatedUnitDisplayOrder] [INT] NULL,
[RelatedUnitName] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
[RelatedUnitAbbreviation] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
[RelatedUnitConversionRatio] [FLOAT] NULL,
[UnitOfMeasureSetID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NULL,
```

Comment: are you inserting a duplicate record? Or a record that contains the same unique key as something else?

Comment: @austinwernli... No. The primary key on the table uses (NewID()) for its default value. So given that, Im not touching that field.

Answer (score 0):

EF treats autoincrement integer identity columns specially. It knows that it shouldn't try to insert 0 or NULL into them. It doesn't respect default values in the same way. Whatever you give it as the value of the primary key, it will attempt to insert into the table. If your ID is `Guid.Empty`, it will try to insert 12 records with `Guid.Empty` and you'll get the error you're having.

The solution is to set the ID to `Guid.NewGuid` in the constructor. This is redundant with the default value of the column, but it doesn't create any problem - you're just creating a new guid whether you do it in EF or the database.

This is what you should do with all default values in EF. The advantage is, let's say you have a bit column and the default is 1. If you create a new entity in code, what do you want the value of that boolean property to be as soon as it is created? `true`, right? So you have to do that in the constructor. If only EF is being used to insert into a database, it's actually the database column default which is redundant, not the default set in the constructor. If other methods are sometimes used to insert into the database, both EF and the database need to enforce the default separately. Then both newly created entities and newly created database rows will have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, Open the .EDMX file, select the PK on the table in question, hit F4 for properties and change the `StoreGeneratedPattern` value to `Identity`.